# CSS :last-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a `div#content` with many `div.item` inside it.
When using `:last-child` to make the last `div.item` with no `border-bottom`, it's OK.
But, as the content is dynamically appended using php and mysql results I'm using a conditional pagination table that will be appended after the last `div.item` which means at the bottom of the `div#content`. Here will be the problem as the CSS `:last-child` will not recognize the last `div.item` as the last-child.
my CSS looks like:

```
div#content div.item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

as you can see I'm defining that the last child id such a `div.item`

Any suggestions please. thanks in advance.

**!!!!! Please note that the problem is not in the fact that the content is dynamic but in the fact that the CSS :last-child doesn't recognize the div.item as the last child but the last element in the div#content despite telling the CSS that it's:**

```
div#content div.item:last-child
```

Comment: Please note that `:last-child` is [not supported in IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t35). What browser are you using?

Comment: @Andrew Vit: Well, if OP says it works fine at first, he must not be using IE.

Comment: Are you sure you're only appending `div.item` at the child level and not anything else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One *possibility* I can think of is that you're appending elements that aren't `<div>`s and/or don't have the `item` class. Check the output of your PHP/MySQL script and see if there are any non-`div.item` elements beside (in DOM terms) the `div.item` elements.

Such elements will not match the selector:

```
div#content div.item:last-child
```

That selector finds only `<div>`s with `item` class, that are the last child of `div#content`.

Here's an example.

**Before appending**

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="item"></div> <!-- [1] Selected -->
</div>
```

**After appending**

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="item"></div> <!-- [2] Not selected -->
  <div></div>              <!-- [3] Not selected -->
</div>
```

**What's being selected, what's not, and *why*?**

1. **Selected**
   This `<div>` element has the `item` class, and it's the last child of `div#content`.

   It exactly matches the above selector.
2. **Not selected**
   This `<div>` element has the `item` class, but is *not* the last child of `div#content`.

   It doesn't exactly match the above selector; however, it can possibly match either one of these selectors:

   ```
   /* Any div.item inside div#content */
   div#content div.item

   /* The last div.item child of its parent only */
   div#content div.item:last-of-type
   ```
3. **Not selected**
   Although this `<div>` element is the last child, it does *not* have the `item` class.

   It doesn't exactly match the above selector; however, it can possibly match this:

   ```
   /* Any div that happens to be the last child of its parent */
   div#content div:last-child
   ```

Comment: Nice explanation. Care to expand to talk about why `div#content div.item:not(.dont-want):last-of-type` wouldn't work as expected?

Comment: @Kevin Peno: Scratch my previous comment. It's because `:not()` is always processed after `:last-of-type`. That means the `:last-of-type` element is checked, then discarded if it hits the `:not()`. See [this modified jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/CfZdN).

Comment: I gotcha, so even though the not selector comes first, not is processed last. That is unfortunate. Do you of any way, with css and without relying on nth*, to accomplish this?

Comment: @Kevin Peno: Can't think of any, but that may be just me typing this at 2 in the morning :P

Answer (score 0):

It seems appending items dinamically does not make the layout engine re-run some CSS rules like :last-child.

I think you can re-read/reload CSS file making the rule apply. Don't know, it's a guess.

Another possibility is dinamically set the styles.

---

EDIT: It seems you have a CSS x Browser problem.

Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29#Selectors

Comment: thank you for your answers but as I said I'm using php and mysql to dynamically generate the div.itemS so before even sending the page to the client.

Comment: @med, so let see if I understand... you have never see this :last-child rule working before? I thought it was a js-dynamic generated. If this is prior sending to client, I assume your CSS rule never worked then. In this case, can you tell me what browser you are using to test?

Answer (score -1):

you could use javascript to refresh the CSS only. See here: http://paulirish.com/2008/how-to-iterate-quickly-when-debugging-css/

Another approach would be to use a library like jQuery and fire this line of script every time you add new divs. (or maybe you're using another js library, as you say that you are dynamically adding divs to the page)

```
$('div#content div.item:last-child').css('borderBottom','none');
```

you might need to reset borders before you do the above though. i.e. the previous 'last' div may still not have the border bottom. so reset all borders then fire the script to remove the border for the last one.

Comment: thank you for your answers but as I said I'm using php and mysql to dynamically generate the div.itemS so before even sending the page to the client.

Comment: @med: ok, then running some javascript after the page has rendered would be one of your options as I've suggested.